# Neo4j-how to create nodes from two columns of CSV file with single MERGE?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am using following code to create a graph

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///fileName.csv"  
AS network
MERGE (n:sourceNode {id:network.node1})
MERGE (m:destNode {id:network.node2})
WITH n,m,network
CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, network.connection, {}, m) yield rel
RETURN n, 
rel, 
m
```

They CSV file contains repeating values like

```
node1,connection,node2
A,0.75,B  
c,0.5,A
```

this code creates a graph like this [image: graph1]
But I need graph like following to perform analysis[image: graph2]
one solution I came up with is that I can create both 
`node1` and `node2` with single `MERGE` clause as it will create non-repeating node. I have tried to modify this code like

```
MERGE (n:sourceNode {id:network.node1}, m:destNode {id:network.node2})
```

and others but I get syntax error. Can some please me out with this situation? or has any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nodes `A`, because in your `MERGE` you are not using the same label.
So at the end you have :

- one node `A` with the label `sourceNode`
- one node `A` with the label `destNode`

If you want to only have one node `A`, please use a common label on both source and destination node, something like that :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:///fileName.csv"  
AS network
MERGE (n:Node {id:network.node1})
MERGE (m:Node {id:network.node2})
WITH n,m,network
CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, network.connection, {}, m) yield rel
RETURN n, 
rel, 
m
```

Moreover on this example you should create a unique constraint on the label `Node` for the property `id` : `CREATE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE;`